# Find out name of PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can PL/SQL procedure in Oracle know it's own name?

Let me explain:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure some_procedure is
    v_procedure_name varchar2(32);
begin
    v_procedure_name := %%something%%;
end;
```

After `%%something%%` executes, variable `v_procedure_name` should contain 'SOME_PROCEDURE'. It is also OK if it contains `object_id` of that procedure, so I can look up name in `all_objects`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try:

```
v_procedure_name := $$PLSQL_UNIT;
```

There's also $$PLSQL_LINE if you want to know which line number you are on.

Comment: Only returns the procedure name for stand alone procedures and functions, if called from a packaged procedure it returns the package name.

Comment: Indeed.  Slightly irritating.

Answer (score 3):

If you are pre-10g, you can 'dig' (parse) it out of
dbms_utility.format_call_stack
Procedures/functions in packages can be overloaded (and nested), so the package name/line number is normally better than the name.

Answer (score 3):

In 10g and 11g I use the "owa_util.get_procedure" function.  I normally use this in packages as it will also return the name of an internal procedure or function as part of the package name, i.e. (package_name).(procedure name).  I use this to provide a generic `EXCEPTION` template for identifying where an exception occured.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure some_procedure is
    v_procedure_name varchar2(32);
begin
    v_procedure_name := owa_util.get_procedure;
end;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE some_package
AS
    FUNCTION v_function_name
    RETURN DATE;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY some_package
AS
    FUNCTION v_function_name
    RETURN DATE
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN SYSDATE;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR IN '||owa_util.get_procedure);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Generates exception for me:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 354
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 2433

on Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0

Comment: @Alexo: same for me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @PeterFrey owa_util is an util package for oracle http applications. And noone will bother to support 10th oracle now. And for 12c oracle try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536323/currently-executing-procedure-name-within-the-package-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat function that takes advantage of REGEXP_SUBSTR.
I've tested it in a package (and it even works if another procedure in the package calls it):

```
FUNCTION SET_PROC RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK, 
             'procedure.+\.(.+)\s', 1,1,'i',1), 'UNDEFINED');
END SET_PROC;
```